U-Boot environment on virtio FAT partition
I'm booting U-Boot in QEMU via Yocto's runqemu command and I'm trying to make the U-Boot to load an environment from FAT partition. Yocto is built from master (312488228ad408fb0f29b2aa272e72cf87de8e93) branch with MACHINE=genericarm64.
The U-Boot version is 2024.07 which seems to contain the commit which add support for loading an environment from virtio interface, see this StackOverflow comment.
I have enabled following options:
CONFIG_ENV_IS_IN_FAT=y
# CONFIG_ENV_IS_IN_FLASH is not set
CONFIG_ENV_FAT_INTERFACE="virtio"
CONFIG_ENV_FAT_DEVICE_AND_PART="0:1"
CONFIG_ENV_FAT_FILE="uboot.env"

following options came along with when enabled the CONFIG_ENV_IS_IN_FAT:
CONFIG_SYS_MMC_ENV_DEV=0
CONFIG_SYS_MMC_ENV_PART=0

I assume the device and part config is correct in CONFIG_ENV_FAT_DEVICE_AND_PART as fatls virtio 0:1 lists the partition content properly. And FAT support is also enabled:
CONFIG_FS_FAT=y
CONFIG_FAT_WRITE=y
CONFIG_FS_FAT_MAX_CLUSTSIZE=65536

But I get the error that virtio is not supported:
Loading Environment from FAT... ** Bad device specification virtio 0 **

Am I missing something crucial here?

The genericarm64.conf defines QB_ROOTFS_OPT like this:
QB_ROOTFS_OPT = "-drive id=root,file=@ROOTFS@,if=none,format=raw -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=root"

but changing it to this:
QB_ROOTFS_OPT = "-drive id=root,file=@ROOTFS@,if=none,format=raw -device virtio-blk-device,drive=root"

makes the environment loading work. So just needed to replace virtio-blk-pci with virtio-blk-device. But I don't know why this makes it work.
